# Structure like Java's EnumSet that can hold repeated elements

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, simulation

I need some structure where to store N Enums, some of them repeated. And be able to easily extract them. So far I've try to use the EnumSet like this.

```
cards = EnumSet.of(
                BEST_OF_THREE,
                BEST_OF_THREE,
                SIMPLE_QUESTION,
                SIMPLE_QUESTION,
                STAR);
```

But now I see it can only have one of each. Conceptually, which one would be the best structure to use for this problem.

Regards
jose

Comment: What do you want to do with the enums after extracting them? What is the usage behaviour: extract all of the same type, consume one (remove one), ...?

Comment: Extract elements randomly (One at the time) until it's empty, then "restart" the structure and start again.

Comment: Randomly in the sense of random access or of picking an arbitrary element?

Comment: Picking an arbitrary element

Comment: I would simply use a ``Queue`` (The ``LinkedList`` implements this interface). Initialize the queue with the items, shuffle it and poll the first element. You don't need a ``Set``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Map of type Enumeration -> Integer, where the integer indicates how many of each there are. The google guava "MultiSet" does this for you, and handles the edge cases of adding an enum to the set when there is not already an entry, and removing an enum when it leaves none left.

Another strategy is to use the Enumeration ordinal index. Because this index is unique, you can use this to index into an int array that is sized to the Enumeration size, where the count in each array slot would indicate how many of each enumeration you have. Like this:

```
// initialize array for counting each enumeration type
// TODO: someone should double check every initial value will be zero
int[] cardCount = new int[CardEnum.values().length];
...

// incrementing the count for an enumeration (when we add)
cardCount[BEST_OF_THREE.ordinal()]++;
...

// decrementing the count for an enumeration (when we remove) 
cardCount[BEST_OF_THREE.ordinal()]--;
// DEBUG: assert cardCount[BEST_OF_THREE.ordinal()] >= 0
...

// getting the count for an enumeration 
int count = cardCount[BEST_OF_THREE.ordinal()];
```

... Some time later

Having read the clarifying comments underneath the original post that explained what the OP was asking, it is clear that you're best off with a linear structure with an entry per element. I didn't realize that you didn't need detailed information on how many of each you needed. Storing them in a MultiSet or an equivalent counting structure makes it hard to randomly pick, as you need to attribute an index picked at random from [0, size) to a particular container, which takes log time.

Comment: Added an example. The main idea is that an enumeration has an index unique to that enumeration class (its ordinal), and you use that index to access an int array sized to the number of enumeration values, and increment/decrement the integer in that slot.

Answer (score 1):

Sets don't allow duplicates, so if you want repeats you'll need either a List or a Map.

If you just need the number of duplicates, an [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) with Integer values is probably your best bet.

If the order is important, and you need quick access to the number of each type, you'll probably need to roll your own data structure.

If the order is important (but the count of each is not), then a List is the way to go, which implementation depends on how you will use it.

- [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) - Best when there will be many inserts/removals from the beginning of the List. Indexing into a LinkedList is very expensive, and should be avoided whenever possible. If a List is built by shifting data onto the front of the list, but any later additions are at the end, conversion to an ArrayList once the initial List is built is a good idea - especially if indexing into the List is anticipated at any point.
- [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - When in doubt, this is a good place to start. Inserting or removing items requires shifting, so if this is a common operation look elsewhere.
- [TreeList](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html) - This is a good all-around option, and insertions and removals anywhere in the List are inexpensive.  This does require the Apache commons library, and uses a bit more memory than the others.

Benchmarks, and the code used go generate them can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/morgen-peschke/6c733744ceb9d1821ccf).

Comment: An ArrayList has a variable size. Your advice on choosing the list implementation, and even more the last advice to use both, are really wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet The ArrayList does have a variable size, but the resize operations are expensive, as are push/pop. In addition,  it's capacity will grow automatically, but no guarantees are made about shrinking when it is no longer needed. On the other hand, indexing into a LinkedList is horribly expensive, and it does make perfect sense to build using a LinkedList when the needed size is unknown (or varies to an unacceptable degree), then use that to build an ArrayList. The cost of building the ArrayList is more than offset the first time the List is used in a for loop.

Comment: They're not as expensive as creating and populating a LinkedList, iterating on it creating an ArrayList from the LinkedList, and garbage-collecting all the linked list nodes. Iterating a large linked list is inefficient. And even if that was more efficient, you'd have to prove using an ArrayList only causes a significant performance problem, solved by populating a LinkedList first, before applying this otherwise premature optimization.

Comment: @JBNizet Inserting or removing an item from the middle of an array backed list involves shifting the object at every index, which is very, very expensive. Yes, with a for loop iterating over a linked list would be horrendously expensive, but jumping from node to node, as in the implementation of `LinkedList#toArray` is reasonably efficient. The documentation on the 3 implementations are somewhat antagonistic toward the other implementations, so my conclusions are based on the general properties of the data structure that hold true regardless of the implementation.

Comment: I'm not discussing that. I'm discussing what you posted in your question: 1. use an ArrayList when the size is known, 2. use use a linked list then an ArrayList. BTW, removing from the middle of a LinkedList, if you have to iterate until the middle element to do it, is inefficient as well.

Comment: If order is important, then used a Map where order is preserved, like a LinkedSet/Map. An ArrayList/LinkedList is a poor approach.

Comment: @Simon The Map would not preserve the order between instances of the same enum object. If, for example, the enum objects represent commands that need to be run in a specific order, the map would maintain order relative to each other, but would mangle a sequence of commands where the various enum objects were intermingled.

Comment: Yes. That's why I said "like," the main idea being that you need to preserve insertion ordering for multiple/repeat elements. I doubt a general use "LinkedMultiSet" exists, but it's not to hard to make one. It would solve the insertion/count/remove problem, with all operations in constant time.

Comment: @JBNizet Unless you are using a TreeList, adding or removing in the middle will be a problem, I'll update the answer to reflect that. I ran a quick benchmark on the two creation methods, as well as building an ArrayList when the size is known, adding 100,000 integers to both the back and front of a list. The code I used is available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/morgen-peschke/6c733744ceb9d1821ccf), Building with a LinkedList, then converting to an ArrayList, was faster by two orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Simon Ahh, that would be a third case, I should add a note about it.

Comment: And I did a test adding 2M new objects 200 times to an ArrayList (default size) and doing the same with a LinkedList, and the linked list takes 128% of the time taken for the ArrayList. Of course adding 1 out of 2 elements to the beginning of an ArrayList takes more time than doing it with a LinkedList, but that's very far from being the typical use-case.

Comment: @JBNizet I'd be interested in seeing the code for your benchmark so I can run it. Understanding the factors that can make such a large performance difference is wonderfully interesting stuff. As an aside, adding to the beginning of the List is not uncommon, particularly when creating the list based on input that is more easily parsed in reverse order.